# Feedback on Traffic Light which revolves around Serial Communication

Tags: c++, c, serialization, arduino, serial-port

**Assignment description**

I'd like to receive feedback on an assignment which I'm currently working on. I have to make two traffic lights which allow traffic to run smoothly. I'm using a master Arduino which handles the main serial communication and one slave Arduino which handles the light sequence. Both lights turn red if the master Arduino is disconnected. *I must use the SoftwareSerial library.* The situation is shown below:
[image: 1]]
 **Wiring** [image] **Code master Arduino**

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial serial(2, 3); // RX, TX

// Timer
unsigned long currentTime;
unsigned long previousTime = 0;
const unsigned long event = 50;

String readString = ""; // String containing serial data
bool sendACK = false;  // Boolean regulating handshaking

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600); // Native USB connection (baudrate 9600)
  Serial.setTimeout(10);
  while (!Serial)
  {
    ; // Wait for serial port to connect
  }
  serial.begin(9600);    // SoftwareSerial connection (baudrate 9600)
  serial.setTimeout(10); // Maximum wait time
}

void loop()
{
  currentTime = millis(); // Set current time

  /* Set string to incoming data. Once request to 'three-way handshake' has been acknowledged,
  set boolean sendACK to true, allowing "ACK" to be sent. */
  if (serial.available() > 0)
  {
    while (serial.available() > 0)
    {
      readString = serial.readString();
      Serial.print(readString);
    }
    if (readString == "SYN-ACK/")
    {
      sendACK = true;
    }
  }

  /* Send "SYN" to initiate 'three-way handshake'. Once connection established, send "ACK" */
  if ((currentTime - previousTime) > event)
  {
    if (sendACK == false)
    {
      serial.print("SYN/");
      Serial.print("SYN/");
    }
    else if (sendACK == true)
    {
      serial.print("ACK/");
      Serial.print("ACK/");
      sendACK = false;
    }
    previousTime = currentTime;
  }
}
```

**Code slave Arduino**

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial serial(8, 9); // RX, TX

// First traffic light LED's
const int redLED1 = 2;
const int yellowLED1 = 3;
const int greenLED1 = 4;

// Second traffic light LED's
const int redLED2 = 5;
const int yellowLED2 = 6;
const int greenLED2 = 7;

long counter = 0; // Counter

bool setLight = false;

// Timer
unsigned long currentTime;
unsigned long previousTime = 0;
const unsigned long event = 200;

String readString = ""; // String containing serial data

void setup()
{
  // Multiple LED outputs
  pinMode(redLED1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(yellowLED1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(greenLED1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(redLED2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(yellowLED2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(greenLED2, OUTPUT);

  serial.begin(9600); // SoftwareSerial connection (baudrate 9600)
  serial.setTimeout(10); // Maximum wait time
}

void loop()
{
  currentTime = millis(); // Set current time

  /* Set string to incoming data. Establish 'three-way handshake' and count the amount
  of times handshaking performed. Set lights according to the handshakes counted. */
  if (serial.available() > 0)
  {
    while (serial.available() > 0)
    {
      readString = serial.readString();
    }
    if (readString == "SYN/")
    {
      serial.print("SYN-ACK/");
    }
    else if (readString == "ACK/")
    {
      switch (counter)
      {
      case 0:
        digitalWrite(redLED1, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(redLED2, HIGH);
        break;

      case 10:
        digitalWrite(greenLED1, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(redLED1, LOW);
        break;

      case 40:
        digitalWrite(yellowLED1, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(greenLED1, LOW);
        break;

      case 50:
        digitalWrite(redLED1, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(yellowLED1, LOW);
        break;

      case 60:
        digitalWrite(greenLED2, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(redLED2, LOW);
        break;

      case 90:
        digitalWrite(yellowLED2, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(greenLED2, LOW);
        break;

      case 100:
        digitalWrite(redLED2, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(yellowLED2, LOW);
        break;
      }
      counter++;
      if (counter > 100)
      {
        counter = 0;
      }
    }
    setLight = false;
    previousTime = currentTime;
  }
  // If handshake did not work, wait for 200 milliseconds and set traffic lights to red.
  else if ((currentTime - previousTime) > event && !setLight)
  {
    digitalWrite(redLED1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(redLED2, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(yellowLED1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(yellowLED2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(greenLED1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(greenLED2, LOW);
    counter = 0;
    setLight = true;
  }
}
```

Please give me feedback on my code and which parts I could do more efficiently.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview@SE. How is this `c++`?

Comment: I have rolled this back to the original code. Please do not update it as a result of feedback; open a new question if you want another round of feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Use a common protocol file

Any common constants, such as

- 9600
- `SYN`, `ACK`, etc. strings

should be `#define`d in one place, in this case a `.h` file accessible to both Arduino projects.

### Indentation

One-space indentation is essentially never used. Typically four is used instead.

### Globals

In the master code, every single one of those globals should be moved to `loop()` and declared `static`. That way they will retain their value through multiple calls but will also have their scope reduced.

### Efficiency

I realize a lot of these may fall outside of the constraints of your assignment; nevertheless:

- Don't use software-serial; use a hardware serial port
- Don't use Arduino; use smaller microcontrollers that are better-suited to your application
- Don't use ASCII string signalling; use single-byte constants. If fidelity is a concern, add a checksum.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I've made the following changes (and edited the code in the main question): 1. Added a header file. I don't know if I should make 3 header files (master Arduino constants, slave Arduino constants and common protocol) or one header like I made. 2. Changed constants and moved most to loop() function. 3. Changed indentation to four. Could you check if I did it correctly? Thanks again :)

Comment: Please do not edit the code in the main question as a result of feedback - CR policy is that you open a new question.

Comment: _I don't know if I should make 3 header files (master Arduino constants, slave Arduino constants and common protocol) or one header like I made._ 3, in my opinion.

Comment: Alright I will open a new question and split the header file into 3